# Specifying filesystem attributes with Azure Storage REST API version >= 2019-02-02

Tags: azure, rest, azure-storage, azure-files, azure-storage-files

I'm trying to use the [Storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file) to create a file in file storage. As of the 2019-02-02 API version, this requires specifying a number of filesystem parameters in the headers. Most of them I can figure out or use the defaults, but one has me stumped:

> - `x-ms-file-attributes`: Required. Version 2019-02-02 and newer. The file system attributes to be set on the file. See the list of available attributes.

The list of available attributes is just a table of Win32 filesystem attributes, which isn't very helpful in a http context.

[image]

The question is, how do I specify these attributes as part of a http[s] request? I've tried various header values like `x-ms-file-attributes: Archive` or `x-ms-file-attributes: None`, but without any luck.

```
InvalidHeaderValue
The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:bf47ff6b-001a-0086-6358-0854b5000000
Time:2020-04-01T19:08:28.8394578Z
x-ms-file-attributes
archive
```

Comment: can you provide more details of how do you using the rest api, via code or some tools like postman? I did test the api, it's ok when using `x-ms-file-attributes: None` or `x-ms-file-attributes: Archive`

Comment: Please share the code. My guess is that somewhere you're converting the `x-ms-file-attributes` header value to lowercase (from `Archive` to `archive`) and that's messing things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x-ms-file-attributes: None` or `x-ms-file-attributes: Archive` should work, and I test it with postman, it works:

[image]

If you're using code, please includes your code in the post so we can check it(do you use `archive` instead of `Archive` in code?). And I have tested this api(version 2019-02-02) with c#, no issues.

Comment: Yeah, I'm finding that my code works now too. No idea what I changed. I'm using R, btw.